# HttpClient and HttpWebRequest cannot make empty Post request

Tags: c#, asp.net

Seems `HttpClient` is not able to perform the following post request (it throws validation errors)

- POST with URI encoded parameters
- no Body but Content-Type header setted.

I'm sure this is a problem of usage of C# since I was able to perform the correct request with Postman (see the image)

[image]

The service I'm trying to authenticate against is this one [Fitbit OAUTH2](https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/oauth2/)

I tried also `HttpWebRequest`, but I failed to do that even with that class, however here's also the second attemp. Seems C# is performing some action different from Postman but I have to figure out which action. Does anyone ever had a similiar issue?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


public static class MyRequest
{
    public static string Call( string uri, string headerName, string header)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create( uri);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.Headers.Add( "Authorization", $"{headerName} {header}");
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        var response = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.GetResponse();

        if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }


        using ( var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            return stream.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

If I use the HttpClient with the following content

```
content = FormUrlEncodedContet( keyValues)
```

the final URL do not have the `#_=_` appended, and that is requested by that service otherwise it returns 401

Comment: `(it throws validation errors)` -- You left out the most important detail of your question.. **What errors** ??

Comment: "that header should be used as "content header"

Comment: Sorry I tried like 10 different approaches so I don't remember all errors I got.

Comment: @UberFace How about adding one or two of those validation errors

Comment: That code won't compile....

Comment: ok now it compiles (provided you install the nuget package)

Comment: Why making a POST request when you don't want to send data in the first place?

Comment: because the service of another companies allow that url to be called only with POST method (like Oauth2 specs require)